# Sequelize - "array_agg" in a "having clause"

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following situation:
Table `computers`, table `flags` and table `computerFlags` that links them.
Table `computerFlags` looks like:

```
computerName | flagId
  computer1  | flag1
  computer1  | flag2
  computer2  | flag2
  computer2  | flag3
```

computer3 does not have any flags, so it is not in the table
I'm working with sequelize, and I'm trying to execute a query to count all computers without "flag3", in the above example table the answer would be 2 ("computer1" and "computer3").

This is the code I have so far:

```js
import { DataTypes, Sequelize, Op } from "sequelize";

(async () => {
    try {
        const postgresDB = new Sequelize('postgres://<my-pg-credentials>>', {
            logging: true,
        });

        const computers = postgresDB.define('computer', {
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            // Other computer fields
        });

        const flags = postgresDB.define('flag', {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            name: DataTypes.TEXT,
        });
        const computerFlags = postgresDB.define('computerFlag', {}, { createdAt: false, updatedAt: false })

        computers.belongsToMany(flags, { through: computerFlags });
        flags.belongsToMany(computers, { through: computerFlags });
        await postgresDB.sync({ alter: true })
        const c = await computers.count({


            distinct: true,
            group: ['computer.name'],
            include: [

                {
                    model: flags

                },
            ]
        });
        } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
})();
```

I get a half-good result with the next SQL query:

```
select count("computerName") from "computerFlags"
group by "computerName"
having '2' != all(array_agg("flagId"))
```

But I can't find a way to produce this in sequelize, and also, for the above table it'll return 1 as 'computer3' is not in the table

To execute this with sequelize, I would like to do something like that:

```js
having: {
  [[Sequelize.fn('array_agg', Sequelize.col('flag.id')), 'flagIds']] : {
    [Op.all]: {
      [Op.ne]: '2'
    }
  }
}
```

But there are two problems with that:

1. I cannot use `[[Sequelize.fn ...]]` as a left operand
2. I'm not sure if the way I refer to the flag ID is correct as it should be something like `computer->flags->flagId`.  `computer->flags` returns an array of flags when I use `findAll`, each one containing `flagId`.

I'm really lost and confuse and I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to execute a query to count all computers without "flag3"

So use [`NOT EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS). (Some would say, a "semi-anti-join".)

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM   computers c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM computerFlags cf
   WHERE  cf.computerName = c.computerName
   AND    cf.flagId = 'flag3'
   );
```

Only eliminates computers from the count that actually do have an entry with 'flag3'.

Should perform best.

Aside: CaMeL case names are not ideal for Postgres. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)